# UITesting in Xcode 7 animations repeat animations make tests fail

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a situation where im running some basic UITests but they fail as I have 2 animations that are set to repeat.

When using the app normally the user can click the login button and continue as these animations dont block the UI/Main thread at all.

However when I run my UITests it fails to Tap on the button and reports the following error.

UI Testing Failure - App failied to quiesce within 30.0 seconds

If I remove the option to repeat the animation the tests work fine and pass.

if I set the repeatcount to 0 the tests will pass too, however this means the actual application does not perform as required.

I tried the following where isRunningTest is a Environment varible and even though it seems to be set. The repeat count seems to be ignored ?

```
    if([AppDelegate isRunningTests])
    {
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    }
```

Is this a bug or is there a work around for this.

My feeling is an animation that is repeating shouldnt cause the tests to fail.

Anyone had a similar experience and solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Some problem, I removed all animations when doing **UITests**.

You can disable animations for the entire app with:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
```